# Excel Formula needed to sum values greater than 5

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column called billing Units in a spreadsheet of all online orders. The client is being billed based on number of units * 0.05 per unit.  This unfortunately doesn't happen unless there are more than 5 units.

I am looking for a formula that will sumif the value is over 5, but of just the difference above 5 units.

Example orders:

```
Order ID:          Billing Units
O11345             5
O11346             7
O11347             20
```

I would be looking for an output of 17.

I have tried `=SUMIF(B2:B6000,">5")` but this comes out as 27 as it includes the 5 units that should be free.

Ryan

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
=SUMIF(B:B,">5") - COUNTIF(B:B,">5") * 5
```

[image]

Comment: That is awesome. Thank you so much, works perfect.

Comment: Clever formula!